Eating habit of a 16 month old toddler
I'm writing here to know if something I'm doing wrong. I have 16 month old toddler who never seems interested in breakfast since 7-8 months.
Sometimes he eats when distracted only whether he drinks morning milk before breakfast or not. He is always fussy in the morning but yes he likes anything to drink so I started giving him smoothy types like Rice or oats powder mixed with dry fruits powder + 1 soaked date with fruit like banana/avocado/pear+ frozen strawberry blended with whole milk available here in riyadh.
Can someone guide me is it ok, should I consider this breakfast or snack? Am I making him habitual of smoothie? Actually I have tried everything like no milk before breakfast, our same adult breakfast, avocado, french toast, pancake etc but he seems never interested.
Our pediatrician suggested him formula till 2 years because till now he has 2 lower teeth so the pediatrician has given reason of vitamin which is not in fresh milk so I give formula only 2 times and whole milk smoothie in breakfast. He seems more interested in fruits, probiotic and dairy whole day rather than grain or cereals.
Please suggest.

Have you asked your pediatrician if what you're doing is good for the child? The pediatrician knows the child and knows if the child has special requirements. Not knowing the child's past medical history and possible problems, it's hard to suggest anything different than what your pediatrician has suggested. Why are you not using formula as the base for a smoothie? Also, if you disagree with the pediatrician, is it possible to get a seconf opinion?  All these questions matter.
